# How to validate a model using annotations without @Valid

Tags: java, spring, validation

In my program I accept a file with phone numbers which I process and add to the database. I can use @Valid annotation only in method parameter, but then how can I use annotations in model fields?

The below method takes a list of already received phone numbers and casts them to NotifyUser
Service:

```
private NotificationResult convertStringToNotifyUser(List<String> records){
    List<NotifyUser> correctPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BadPhoneNumber> badPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String record: records){
        NotifyUser notifyUser = new NotifyUser();
        notifyUser.setPhone_number(record.trim());

        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(notifyUser, "notifyUser");
        notifyUserValidator.validate(notifyUser, errors);
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            badPhoneNumbers.add(new BadPhoneNumber(record, errors.getFieldErrors()));
        }
        else {
            correctPhoneNumbers.add(notifyUser);
        }
    }
    return new NotificationResult(correctPhoneNumbers, badPhoneNumbers);
}
```

Model:

```
public class NotifyUser {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Phone number cannot be empty")
    @Size(min = 11, max = 12, message = "the phone number can start with +7 or 8 and have 11 or 12 characters respectively")
    private String phone_number;

    //other code
```

I have an idea that I could manually write the validation logic identical to the model field annotations, but then I would just be duplicating the logic, which doesn't seem like good practice.

Comment: Spring provides a validator bean, autowire it in your service.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;

@Autowired
private Validator validator;

Set<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(notifyUser);

for (ConstraintViolation constraintViolation : violations) {
badPhoneNumbers.add(new BadPhoneNumber(record, constraintViolation.getMessage()));}

This is a Spring Validator that envokes the annotations to be validated against your model object

Comment: So Spring Validator can check the validation of annotations from Jakarta?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Take a look at:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html

It explains in here: 

"When used as org.springframework.validation.Validator, LocalValidatorFactoryBean invokes the underlying jakarta.validation.Validator, and then adapts ContraintViolations to FieldErrors, and registers them with the Errors object passed into the validate method."

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem was. The basic Spring validator automatically knows how to work with validation annotations in the model (like @Valid). However, if I create a new validator that implements the Validator interface, then Spring will not be able to validate against annotations. As a result, I solved my problem by adding a basic validator and performing validation.

```
private final NotifyUserValidator notifyUserValidator;
private final Validator baseValidator;

@Autowired
public FileHandlerService(NotifyUserValidator notifyUserValidator, LocalValidatorFactoryBean baseValidator) {
    this.notifyUserValidator = notifyUserValidator;
    this.baseValidator = baseValidator;
}

//other code

private NotificationResult convertStringToNotifyUser(List<String> records){
    List<NotifyUser> correctPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BadPhoneNumber> badPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String record: records){
        NotifyUser notifyUser = new NotifyUser();
        notifyUser.setPhone_number(record.trim());

        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(notifyUser, "notifyUser");
        notifyUserValidator.validate(notifyUser, errors);
        baseValidator.validate(notifyUser, errors);
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            badPhoneNumbers.add(new BadPhoneNumber(record, errors.getFieldErrors()));
        }
        else {
            correctPhoneNumbers.add(notifyUser);
        }
    }
    return new NotificationResult(correctPhoneNumbers, badPhoneNumbers);
}
```